# Adicionar where's na consulta se receber parâmetro de filtro no adonis/node

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Atualmente eu possuo essa query que retorna todos os usuários:

```
async index({request}) {
    const page = request.input('page')
    const pageSize = request.input('pageSize')
    const users = await User
        .query()
        .with('user')
        .paginate(page, pageSize)
    return users.toJSON()
}
```

Eu preciso criar condicionalmente uma forma de inserir dois where caso tenha parâmetro de filtro.

Por exemplo, se receber `request.input('username')` adicionar uma cláusula `where`:

```
.whereRaw('username = %?%', [request.input('username')])
```

Não consegui encontrar na documentação algo que explicasse como criar condicionalmente `where`. Alguém poderia me fornecer um exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se alguém precisar, eu consegui resolver dessa forma:

```
async index({request}) {
    const { page, pageSize } = request.get();
    const queryUsers = User
        .query()
        .with('user')

    if(request.input('username'))
        queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+request.input('username')+'%')

    const users = await queryUsers.paginate(page, pageSize)

    return users
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigato